# How to change caret blinking speed/rate in Sublime Text 3 on Linux Mint 18.1?

Tags: sublimetext3, linux-mint

I am currently using SciTE as a text and code editor and can there adjust the caret blinking rate by specifying in the ".SciTEUser.properties" file

```
caret.period=350
```

Now I am evaluating the features of Sublime Text 3 (I am using Linux Mint 18.1 if it does matter) and can't find a way to change the caret blinking rate there.

All what I found out about setting caret properties in Sublime Text 3 is:

```
// Valid values are "smooth", "phase", "blink" and "solid".
"caret_style":       "phase",
"caret_extra_top":    1,
"caret_extra_bottom": 1,
"caret_extra_width":  7,
```

but can't find something like `caret_blinking_rate` or `caret_frequency` or `caret_period`.

> How can I change the caret blinking rate/speed in Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the undocumented parameter, [`"caret_blink_interval"`](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-2084/2008/6):

> There's another hidden setting btw: "caret_blink_interval", which is the time in seconds to complete a blink cycle. A value of 0 (the default) means use the OS settings.

You probably want to add something like

```
"caret_blink_interval": 0.35,
```

to your `Preferences.sublime-settings`.

Comment: I've also needed to add `"caret_style": ""`.

Comment: Thanks. Works well on mac with build 4113 for `"caret_style": "phase"`.

Comment: `"caret_style": "blink"`

Answer (score 2):

[ST picks up the caret blink speed from the OS settings.](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-2084/2008?u=kingkeith) Consequently, there is no way to change it from within ST to a different value.

I'm not sure where to find the setting on Mint, but on Ubuntu Mate 17.04, it is in the System menu -> Preferences -> Hardware -> Keyboard, and then General -> Cursor Blinking -> Speed.

[image: Ubuntu Mate Keyboard Preferences]

For completeness, in case others are interested, this is where it is set on Windows 7:

Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Devices and Printers -> (Find your Keyboard). Right click -> Keyboard Settings, and then Speed -> Cursor blink rate.

[image: Windows Keyboard Preferences]

Comment: In Linux Mint (Cinnamon) it's the same way of setting the Cursor blink rate as you describe and yes the change there is mirrored in Sublime. By the way: playing with this setting (setting blinking to OFF) crashed Sublime (it didn't respond requiring forced close - but after a restart it worked again with not blinking caret/cursor). System-wide applied speedy caret means fast blinking also in the Terminal window where because of the size of the caret/cursor (full block) it is not really acceptable. **Let's say this point goes to SciTE.**